# scala slick - how to name yielded fields?

Tags: scala, slick

In Slick I can do this:

```
  val joinQuery: Query[(Rep[String], Rep[String]), (String, String), Seq] = for {
    c <- coffees if c.price > 9.0
    s <- c.supplier
  } yield (c.name, s.name)
```

Then I can access name like this:

```
  joinQuery.map(_._1)
```

But I am not confortable using _1 to access the name.

Is there any way I can name the yielded fields?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean something like `joinQuery.map{ case (coffeeName, supName) => //whatever }` ? (note the curly! braces)

Answer (score 2):

Well... you can define your case class for result types, and use them to Shape the query result.

```
case class YourQueryResult(coffeeName: String, supplierName: String)

val joinQuery = for {
  c <- coffees if c.price > 9.0
  s <- c.supplier
} yield (c.name, s.name)

val joinQueryResultFuture = database.run(joinQuery).map(seq => {
  seq.map({ case (coffeeName, supplierName) => YourQueryResult(coffeeName, supplierName) })
})
```

But, lets say you want to further modify the query itself, you can use pattern matching,

```
val joinQuery = for {
  c <- coffees if c.price > 9.0
  s <- c.supplier
} yield (c.name, s.name)

val modificationQuery = joinQuery.map({
  case (coffeeName, supplierName) => coffeeName
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to do with an anonymous class?

Comment: I had to create: case class CoffeeSupliersResult(name: Rep[String], name1: Rep[String]) so it would compile (with Rep[String]). But it throws an exception "No matching Shape found".

Comment: I was still in the middle of writing the answer at that time. Somehow posted the in-complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

That probably didn't work yet at that time, but now you can do the following by using `mapTo[]` - hope this helps whoever stumbles across this question.

```
case class YourQueryResult(coffeeName: String, supplierName: String)

val joinQuery = for {
  c <- coffees if c.price > 9.0
  s <- c.supplier
} yield (c.name, s.name).mapTo[YourQueryResult]
```

and then access as

```
joinQuery.map(_.coffeeName)
```